# SDI-display a dialog via a seleted popup menu item

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog, sdi

I have a SDI application and I would like to display a dialog after selecting a popup menu item to call it 
My dialog class is defined as:

```
class Dialog:public CDialogEx
{};
```

and an added function to view class named OnCallDlg does something as simple as:

```
void CAppView::OnCallDlg()
{
   Dialog d;
   d.DoModal();
```

}

But there is nothing shown up after I choose an item in the popup menu when rightmouse clicking the view.

Comment: Do you handle the `WM_COMMAND` message corresponding to the selected item in the context menu? Where are you calling the `OnCallDlg` function?

Comment: Yes, I do it via add-function wizard and on the CAppView class, the debug shows I reach the call DoModal, only that it returns me -1. By the way, I am using VS10.

Comment: You missed step 2 in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wb9s9ah.aspx

Comment: Yeah, as Hans indicates, you forgot to actually create the dialog to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the ID to your dialog using following pattern:

Dialog  d(ID_DIG);
d.doModal();